# Iterate over array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to iterate over an array that contains the end of a url so I can then 'concatenate' to the main site domain with the aim to gain a fully functional url (ie. [www.mainUrlDomain.com/some-url](http://www.mainUrlDomain.com/some-url))

This is my code:

```
<div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Symbol</th>
                        </tr>
                        {data.map(data => (
                            <tr key={data.code}>
                                <td>
                                    <Image
                                        src={`${mainUrlDomain}/${data.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
                                        width={30}
                                        height={20}
                                    />
                                </td>
                               {landingPagesKeys.includes(`${data.code}`)
                               ? 
                               <Link
                               href={`${mainUrlDomain}/${landingPages}`}
                           >    
                               <td>
                                   <a>{data.name}</a>
                               </td>
                           </Link> : <td>{data.name}</td>}

                                <td>{data.code}</td>
                                <td>{data.symbol}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))})
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

I have tried to add a way to iterate over the `landingPages` array like this:

```
{landingPagesKeys.includes(`${data.code}`)
                                   ? 
{landingPages.map(data => (
                                   <Link
                                   href={`${mainUrlDomain}/${data`}
                               >    
                                   <td>
                                       <a>{data.name}</a>
                                   </td>
                               </Link> )} : <td>{data.name}</td>}
    
                                    <td>{data.code}</td>
                                    <td>{data.symbol}</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))})
```

Unfortunately it didn't show me the array data as expected which contains the end of the desired url (ie. some-url) and `landingPages` after the url domain as the first example of code shows the entire array.

How to map through the array and obtain each individual url that `landingPages` contains?

Comment: data looks to be an object. The second park of your href should probably data.something

Comment: I have turned it into an array by doing this `const landingPages = []
    Object.values(data).forEach(val=>landingPages.push(val))`

Comment: Even if it's an array, you shouldn't be interpolating it here `href={\`${mainUrlDomain}/${landingPages}\`}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` function to filter the data in an array.

```
landingPages.filter(data => landingPagesKeys.includes(`${data.code}`)).map(data => <div>...</div>)
```